# Pass an Array in ListModel

Tags: javascript, qml

I'm wondering how can I pass an array in ListModel?

ok, In QML I have a ListView and I set it's `ListModel` like so:

```
model: ListModel
{
    id: myList   
    ListElement 
    {
        name: ""
        card: 0
        books: []
    }

}
```

I can append to it by using:

```
myList.append({name:"terry", card:00100, books:["024589","865976","879582","215645"]});
```

but when I try to output it on screen I get this.

```
{
    "card": 00100
    "books": {
        "objectName": "",
        "count": 4,
        "dynamicRoles": false
     },
    "name": "terry",
    "name": "terry"
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting 2 names though! and how can I get the value of **books**?

I look up the QML documentation of [ListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html) and [ListElement](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html) couldn't find anything related to passing an array, all the examples are integer or string.

Any idea how I can get the date?
I did work around it by calling the array in **Delegate** with `Component.onCompleted:{}` but I believe that's not a good/correct way since **Delegate** is not responsible for holding the data and should be done in **Model**, please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks for your time.

**Edit01:** Thanks for the reply, here is the reason I need array:
 I have a **ComboBox** in **Delegate** like so:

```
delegate: Rectangle
    {
     id: rowID
     width: 50
     height: 40
     color: "#323232"
     Row
     {
         anchors.fill: parent
         anchors.leftMargin: 10
         anchors.rightMargin: 10
         Label{
             id: nameID
             text: name
             font.pixelSize: 12
             width: 200
             wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
             anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
             color: "#999"
         }

         Label{
             anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
             text: "out:"
             font.pixelSize: 12
             color: "#999"
         }

         ComboBox{
             id: booksID
             height: 20
             width: 50
             model: books
             anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
         }
     }
}
```

as you can see I'm feeding the **name** to **Label** (**id: nameID**) and I want to feed the **books** to **ComboBox** (**id: booksID**) that has **model**, if I make books key as **ListElement** how can I feed all the values?

in QML [ListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html) or [ListElement](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html) documentation didn't mention anything about getting all the key's value right? it only supports `get(int index)` which is based on an index number.

Comment: Just a guess from a quick look at the docs, try `books: [ ListElement "" ]` in the model.

Comment: @T4rk1n I get this `UiError: widget creation failed` but then when I make ListElement is equal to JSON right? which means I need to give it keys and values, but having Array sounds simpler and straight forward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You did that wrong. Array members must be `ListElement`:

```
ListModel {
    id: mod
    ListElement {
        name: "ali"
        dic: [ ListElement{text:"asad-o-llah"; code: 14}, ListElement{text:"aboo torab"; code: 72}, ListElement{text:"amir al-momenin"; code: 110}]
    }
}

ListView {
    model: mod
    anchors.fill: parent
    delegate: Component {
        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width; height: 50
            Row {
                Text {
                    text: name
                }
                ComboBox {
                    width: 100; height: 30
                    model: dic        //<-- set dic as model for combo box
                    textRole: "text"  //<-- important!
                    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                        console.log("current code is "+model.get(currentIndex).code);   //<-- get code value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Component.onCompleted: {
    var v = mod.get(0).dic.get(0).value;    //<-- sample usage
    console.log(v);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. but that's sort of dictionary/Json like with keys and value, let say that I want to use it for **ComboBox** in **Delegate**, how can I feed the ListElement value in ComboBox model? ListElement doesn't have any option to give all the key's value right?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how to use sub-model in a ComboBox.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for `textRole`, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi how would you use `append()` to add new elements?

Comment: Found an answer, on SE.Ubuntu of all places: https://askubuntu.com/a/714306

Answer (score 4):

Do you want some thing similar to this:

```
Rectangle {

id: root
visible: true
width: 360
height: 360

ListModel
{
    id: myList
    ListElement {
           name: "Story"
           card: 3
           books: [
               ListElement { bookName: "Story 1" },
               ListElement { bookName: "Story 2" },
               ListElement { bookName: "Story 3" }
           ]
       }
       ListElement {
           name: "Novel"
           card: 3
           books: [
               ListElement { bookName: "Novel 1" },
               ListElement { bookName: "Novel 2" },
               ListElement { bookName: "Novel 3" }
           ]
       }
}


Component {
    id: displayDelegate
    Rectangle
        {
         id: rowID
         width: 300 //50
         height: 40
         color: "#323232"
         border.color: "white"
         Row
         {
             anchors.fill: parent
             anchors.leftMargin: 10
             anchors.rightMargin: 10
             Text{
                 id: nameID
                 text: name
                 font.pixelSize: 12
                 width: 50 //200
                 wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
                 /*anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter*/
                 color: "white"//"#999"
             }

             Text{
                 /*anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter*/
                 text: "out:"
                 font.pixelSize: 12
                 color: "white"//"#999"
             }

             /*ComboBox{
                 id: booksID
                 height: 20
                 width: 50
                 model: books
                 anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
             }*/
             Repeater {
                 model: books
                 Text { text: bookName + "\t"; color: "white" }
             }
         }
    }
}

ListView {
    id: disp
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: myList
    delegate: displayDelegate
}

}
```

I have modified few line of the code which you have shared. I am not sure about your ComboBox implementation. Therefore, I have used my own implementation of Repeater. You can try to execute and check the result.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to working with ListModel and ListElement, you can also have a look at the *QSyncable JsonListModel* QML type. (It is an open-source component by Ben Lau, you can find it on GitHub here: https://github.com/benlau/qsyncable)

The JsonListModel is a specialized ListModel type, that can handle JSON Arrays that you e.g. create in your QML or fetch from a REST service. It automatically synchronizes the JSON to a QML ListModel, so its very convenient to use:

```
ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent

        // property for json data, used as source for JsonListModel
        property var jsonData: []

        // use JsonListModel as model
        model: JsonListModel {
          source: listView.jsonData
          keyField: "id"
        }

        // delegate
        delegate: DelegateItem { /* ... */ }
}
```

You can also find a comprehensive guide how it works here: [JsonListModel guide](https://v-play.net/apps/avoid-cpp-models-qt)