# TypeError: Cannot read property 'days' of undefined in qml

Tags: qt, qml, typeerror, listmodel

Below is a snippet of my code in which I get the error above.`days` is nested model:

```
ApplicationWindow {
id:appWindow
width: 1000
height: 600
visible:true
flags:Qt.FramelessWindowHint
//color: "transparent"

 property var monthName:0
 property string notesText: monthlistModel.get(monthofdayCalendar.currentIndex).days.get(newdayCalendar.currentIndex).hours.get(dayList.currentIndex).notes

   Settings {
       property alias notesText: appWindow.notesText
   }
```

Below is the `listmodel` with nested models:

```
                  ListModel{
                      id:monthlistModel
                      Component.onCompleted: {
                                 let months = [
                                                {
                                                        monthName: 0,
                                                        days: createDays(31) 
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        monthName: 1,
                                                        days: createDays(29)
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        monthName:2,
                                                        days: createDays(31)
                                                },
                                                 {
                                                        monthName: 3,
                                                        days: createDays(30)
                                                },
                                                 {
                                                        monthName:4,
                                                        days: createDays(31)
                                                },
                                                 {
                                                        monthName: 5,
                                                        days: createDays(30)
                                                },
                                                 {
                                                        monthName: 6,
                                                        days: createDays(31)
                                                },
                                                 {
                                                        monthName: 7,
                                                        days: createDays(31)
                                                },
                                                 {
                                                        monthName:8,
                                                        days: createDays(30)
                                                },
                                                 {
                                                        monthName: 9,
                                                        days: createDays(31)
                                                },
                                                 {
                                                        monthName: 10,
                                                        days: createDays(30)
                                                },
                                                 {
                                                        monthName: 11,
                                                        days: createDays(31)
                                                }
                                    ]
                            append(months)
                    }
                     function createDays(dayCount) {
                            let days = []

                            for (let i = 0; i < dayCount+1; i++) {
                                    days.push({
                                                            day: i ,
                                                            hours: createHours()
                                                        }
                                                        )
                            }
                            return days
                    }

                    function createHours() {
                            let hours = []
                            for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                                    hours.push({
                                                            hour: i,
                                                            notes: ""
                                                        }
                                                        )
                            }
                            return hours
                    }
            }
```

The application code is in below link

https://gist.github.com/cgiannakidis70/a5f0f73440013424fc0dedd7e3300f75

How to solve the above error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is in heavy need of some refactoring in general.

That point aside, your ListModel should contain ListElements, not javascript objects and nested arrays. Might be worth a good readthrough on the [ListModel documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html). Here's a somewhat-related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156895/pass-an-array-in-listmodel) to help out a little more.