# "modelData is not defined", inside repeater inside delegate

Tags: qt, qml, delegates

I would like to place swaths of color, as shown in the following picture.

My qml experiments have been unsuccessful, I get `ReferenceError: modelData is not defined` for the color, even though the count property seems fine. Please see my latest attempt, and the picture of the execution.

Please help me find my mistakes, I assumed that `selectionColors` would be known and recognized by the repeater as a simple string list but only its size seems to work. I don't know how to get my colors to be visible. Trying a locally defined string list model seems to work.

[image]

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    ListModel { id: myModel }

    // The data will come from outside, that is why I used a function for my example
    Component.onCompleted: {
        myModel.append({"fieldName": "lastName", "selectionColors": ["purple"]});
        myModel.append({"fieldName": "cellPhone","selectionColors": ["red"]});
        myModel.append({"fieldName": "firstName","selectionColors": []});
        myModel.append({"fieldName": "birthday", "selectionColors": ["cyan", "yellow"]});
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#B2EBF2"
        ListView {
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: myModel
            spacing: 10
            delegate: FieldDelegate { }
        }
    }
}
```

FieldDelegate.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Rectangle {
    height: 32
    width: parent.width
    anchors.margins: 8
    color: "#80CBC4"

    Row {
        spacing: 20
        x: parent.x
        y: 0
        height: parent.height
        width: 20 * selectionColors.count

        Repeater  {
            model:  selectionColors   // ["red", "blue"]
            Rectangle {
                height: parent.height
                width: 20
                color: modelData
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted: console.log(selectionColors.count);
    }

    Text {
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 60
        text: fieldName
        font.pixelSize: 16
        color: "black"
    }
}
```

I am using Qt 5.12.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you can't nest a pure array in a ListModel. When you output the content like this

```
Component.onCompleted: console.log(selectionColors,
                                   selectionColors.count,
                                   selectionColors.get(0))
```

you will get the following

```
qml: QQmlListModel(0x56094fbc5c90) 1 QObject(0x5609500cecb0)
```

indicating that `selectionColors` itself is a ListModel which contains QObjects. These QObjects don't have any means of getting the data out. This is just a wild guess...I'll further investigate. This [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#example-usage) also shows the usage of nested ListModels with ListElements like I've used it.

```
ListModel {
    id: fruitModel

    ListElement {
        name: "Apple"
        cost: 2.45
        attributes: [
            ListElement { description: "Core" },
            ListElement { description: "Deciduous" }
        ]
    }
    ...
}
```

You can solve your issue by using ListElements as `selectionColors` with named roles `colors`.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel { id: myModel }

    // The data will come from outside, that is why I used a function for my example
    Component.onCompleted: {
        myModel.append({"fieldName": "lastName", "selectionColors": { "colors": ["purple"]}});
        myModel.append({"fieldName": "cellPhone","selectionColors": { "colors": ["red"]}});
        myModel.append({"fieldName": "firstName","selectionColors": { "colors": []}});
        myModel.append({"fieldName": "birthday", "selectionColors": { "colors": ["cyan", "yellow"]}});
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#B2EBF2"

        ListView {
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: myModel
            spacing: 10
            delegate: Rectangle {
                required property string fieldName
                required property var selectionColors

                width: ListView.view.width
                height: 32
                color: "#80CBC4"

                Row {
                    spacing: 20
                    width: 20 * selectionColors.colors.count
                    height: parent.height

                    Repeater {
                        model: selectionColors.colors

                        Rectangle {
                            height: parent.height
                            width: 20
                            color: modelData
                        }
                    }
                }

                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: fieldName
                    font.pixelSize: 16
                    color: "black"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

When you create your model like this

```
ListModel {
    id: myModel

    ListElement {
        fieldName: "lastName"
        selectionColors: ["purple"]
    }
    ListElement {
        fieldName: "cellPhone"
        selectionColors: ["red"]
    }
    ListElement {
        fieldName: "firstName"
        selectionColors: []
    }
    ListElement {
        fieldName: "birthday"
        selectionColors: ["cyan", "yellow"]
    }
}
```

It will actually tell you the reason why your approach isn't working.

```
ListElement: cannot use script for property value
```

After revisiting my previous solution I think the following is better.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel { id: myModel }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        myModel.append({"fieldName": "lastName", "selectionColors": [ {"name": "purple"} ]});
        myModel.append({"fieldName": "cellPhone", "selectionColors": [ {"name": "red"} ]});
        myModel.append({"fieldName": "firstName", "selectionColors": []});
        myModel.append({"fieldName": "birthday", "selectionColors": [ {"name": "cyan"}, {"name": "yellow"} ]});
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#B2EBF2"

        ListView {
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: myModel
            spacing: 10
            delegate: Rectangle {
                required property string fieldName
                required property var selectionColors

                width: ListView.view.width
                height: 32
                color: "#80CBC4"

                Row {
                    spacing: 20
                    width: 20 * selectionColors.count
                    height: parent.height

                    Repeater {
                        model: selectionColors

                        delegate: Rectangle {
                            required property string name

                            height: parent.height
                            width: 20
                            color: name
                        }
                    }
                }

                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: fieldName
                    font.pixelSize: 16
                    color: "black"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html#details) states

> The names used for roles must begin with a lower-case letter and
> should be common to all elements in a given model. Values must be
> simple constants; either strings (quoted and optionally within a call
> to QT_TR_NOOP), boolean values (true, false), numbers, or enumeration
> values (such as AlignText.AlignHCenter).

Comment: This is still weird. I don't understand why this is one level of further ListElement nesting works...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156895/pass-an-array-in-listmodel

Answer (score 2):

For this type of problem, there are a number of alternatives that you may wish to consider:

1. Use JavaScript array instead of ListModel, e.g.

```js
property var myModel: [
   {"fieldName": "lastName", "selectionColors": ["purple"]},
   {"fieldName": "cellPhone","selectionColors": ["red"]},
   {"fieldName": "firstName","selectionColors": []},
   {"fieldName": "birthday", "selectionColors": ["cyan", "yellow"]}
]
```

N.B. must be fully declared before assigned to ListView, since subsequent array pushes will not update the ListView. Also members must be accessed via modelData.fieldName and modelData.selectionColors.

2. Store selectionColors as a string,

```
ListModel { id: myModel }
Component.onCompleted: {
    myModel.append({"fieldName": "lastName", "selectionColors": "purple"});
    myModel.append({"fieldName": "cellPhone","selectionColors": "red"});
    myModel.append({"fieldName": "firstName","selectionColors": ""});
    myModel.append({"fieldName": "birthday", "selectionColors": "cyan,yellow"});
}
```

To access the values you can use fieldName and selectionColors.split(",") to recover the JavaScript array.

3. As a variation to 2, you can store selectionColors as a stringied JavaScript array:

```
ListModel { id: myModel }
Component.onCompleted: {
    myModel.append({"fieldName": "lastName", "selectionColors": '["purple"]'});
    myModel.append({"fieldName": "cellPhone","selectionColors": '["red"]'});
    myModel.append({"fieldName": "firstName","selectionColors": '[]'});
    myModel.append({"fieldName": "birthday", "selectionColors": '["cyan","yellow"]'});
}
```

You can access the data using fieldName and JSON.parse(selectionColors).

4. Use ListModel but move the selectionColors to a separate JSON object, e.g.

```
ListModel {
    id: myModel
    ListElement { fieldName: "lastName" }
    ListElement { fieldName: "cellPhone" }
    ListElement { fieldName: "firstName" }
    ListElement { fieldName: "birthDay" }
}
property var selectionColors: ({
    "lastName": ["purple"],
    "cellPhone": ["red"],
    "firstName": [],
    "birthday": ["cyan","yellow"]
})
```

N.B. The data is split, for fieldNames you access via model.fieldName (or fieldName) but, to access the colors you need to look it up, e.g. selectionColors[model.fieldName]

5. Use Qt6.4 list type:

```
property list<var> myModel
Component.onCompleted: {
    myModel.push({"fieldName": "lastName", "selectionColors": ["purple"]});
    myModel.push({"fieldName": "cellPhone","selectionColors": ["red"]});
    myModel.push({"fieldName": "firstName","selectionColors": []});
    myModel.push({"fieldName": "birthday", "selectionColors": ["cyan", "yellow"]});
}
```

To access the above, it is similar to the array version with modelData.fieldName and modelData.selectionColors. The advantage with the Qt6.4 list-syntax is it behaves like a ListModel in that calls to push will be reflected in the ListView and it is like an JavaScript object because you can support complex JavaScript types like objects and arrays.

If you want to try all 5 answers, you can [see an online implementation.](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of ListModel. When implementing your actual use case use your own QAbstractListModel if the model is dynamic or a plain js array if it is not.

ListModel is for prototyping.